# append text to sql field using Parameters.Add()

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

can any one please help. I have a table with three fields a field Amount, LatestUpdate and Note, I want to update the three fields using parameters to avoid any sql injection. I need help on writing them the correct way using parameter.Add(). 
here is the code.

```
com.CommandText = "update tblStore set Amount=Amount + @amount, LatestUpdate=@latestUpdate, Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),@notes) + '. " + item.notes + "' WHERE ID=1";
com.Parameters.Add("@amount", item.amount.ToString());
com.Parameters.Add("@latestUpdate", item.fuelingDate.ToString());
com.Parameters.Add("@notes", item.notes.ToString());
```

Comment: What are the types of your columns? And why do you need `item.notes` with string concatenation? In this way, it gets a weird syntax.

Comment: looks liek you should use AddWithValue insead of Add in this code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Try it.  If you get an error, tell us what the error is.

Comment: @Ewan [`AddWithValue` _might_ be dangerous for some cases](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The correct way is to provide  the `SqlDbType`. With that overload you also circumvent an issue with `int` as second argument that is mistakenly  used as `SqlDbType` and you prevent wrong implicit casts since ADO.NET has to make a guesses with `AddWithValue`.

Comment: that's interesting. i didn't know that!. I think my answer will fix the code though :)

Comment: also the query string is weird, you are using a combination of string building and parameters. are you tryign to append the item.notes to the notes field?

Comment: my types of coulums are amount= int, latestupdate= datetime, Note=nvarchar. I want to append the text in the Notes field, and the item.notes is an object..  It is workinf fine with parameters.addwithvalue,  but I want to use Add() accourding to some recomndations here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the final code that works, I am sharing it in case anyone else needs it. Thank you all for your help.

```
com.CommandText = "update tblStore set Amount=Amount + @amount, LatestUpdate=@latestUpdate, Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),Notes) + '.' + @notes WHERE ID=1";
                com.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.amount; ;
                com.Parameters.Add("@latestUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = item.fuelingDate; ;
                com.Parameters.Add("@notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = item.notes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameters along with the SqlDBType. Do not use the AddWithValue method because several article mention that it is not very safe. I would use the following:

```
com.CommandText = "update tblStore set Amount=Amount + @amount, LatestUpdate=@latestUpdate, Notes = @notes WHERE ID=1";
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@amount",  System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
parameter.Value = item.amount;
com.Parameters.Add(parameter);

parameter = new SqlParameter("@latestUpdate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value = item.fuelingDate;
com.Parameters.Add(parameter);

parameter = new SqlParameter("@notes", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
parameter.Value = item.notes;
com.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

--UPDATE--

To update the notes instead of overwriting, just change the commandText:

```
com.CommandText = "update tblStore set Amount=Amount + @amount, LatestUpdate=@latestUpdate, Notes = Notes + @notes WHERE ID=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.. You want something like

```
com.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.amount;;
com.Parameters.Add("@latestUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = item.fuelingDate;;
com.Parameters.Add("@notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = item.notes;
```

Don't forget to include `using System.Data;`

Comment: it is working fine, the only problem here is the Note field. it is beeing replace with new text, I want to append, keep the existing text. and add the new text. how can i do that using parameters.Add()

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the new text to the exisiting one in the same column?

Comment: Izzy. yes, I want to add the new text to the existing text in Notes.

Comment: For that you'll have to update your query it has nothing to do with `Add()`

Comment: this is my question, how can i use parameters.add() on this exampole..? set Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),@notes) + '." + item.notes + "' WHERE ID=1";

Comment: This should work `set Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),@notes) + '.' + @notes  WHERE ID=1;`

Answer (score -1):

are you looking for this ?

```
com.CommandText = "update tblStore set Amount=Amount + @amount,
LatestUpdate=@latestUpdate, Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),@notes) + '. " +
item.notes + "' WHERE ID=1";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", item.amount.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latestUpdate", item.fuelingDate.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", item.notes.ToString());
```

Comment: _I need help on writing them the correct way using `parameter.Add()`_

Comment: as stated by `Soner` using `AddWithValue` is dangerous